# Count on a range of values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has two columns - Customer ID and number of products they purchased.

What SQL statement would I use to know how many customers purchased 1 or more products, 2 or more products, 3 or more products etc?

Can this be done WITHOUT using Cross Joins (I'm using google bigquery which does not support that).

Answer (score 4):

If you truly need to count the number of customers who purchase "one or more" and "two or more" separately, you'll need a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN NumOfProducts >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Purchased_1_or_more
     , SUM(CASE WHEN NumOfProducts >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Purchased_2_or_more
     , SUM(CASE WHEN NumOfProducts >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Purchased_3_or_more
     , SUM(CASE WHEN NumOfProducts >= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Purchased_4_or_more
     , SUM(CASE WHEN NumOfProducts >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Purchased_5_or_more
FROM Customers
```

And so on for however many categories you want.

Comment: Yes but I think the poster needs this for all possible values of N, not just 1..5

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
SELECT 
CASE NumOfProducts >= 1 THEN 1
WHEN NumOfProducts >= 2 THEN 2
WHEN NumOfProducts >= 3 THEN 3
ELSE 0
END CASE,
COUNT(CustomerID) AS cnt
FROM Customers
GROUP BY CASE NumOfProducts >= 1 THEN 1
WHEN NumOfProducts >= 2 THEN 2
WHEN NumOfProducts >= 3 THEN 3
ELSE 0
END;
```

Comment: Pretty close; I don't think you need to `GROUP BY COUNT(NumOfProducts)`, just `GROUP BY NumOfProducts`.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The question is how many customers purchase 1 *or more*. That should be emphasized in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible using straight SQL without cross-product.

The reason is following - the operation we care about to do collapsing is using "group by". However the way group by works, is it takes multiple rows and collapses them into **one** row while performing some aggregate calculation.

To do this kind of "one or more" analysis one row needs to be part of the calculation of multiple rows. i.e. the row for the user that has purchased 10 products needs to be part of the rows "1 or more", "2 or more", "3 or more", etc. There's no operation that lets you do this.